# Repairing after "mv /* ../"

Tags: filesystem

After leaving my laptop with an open root shell on my desk (running ubuntu 13.10), some not so nice person bricked my system using "mv /* ../"

Is there any easy way to fix this or am I better off saving what can be saved and reformatting?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls /`? I don't think any changes have been made anyways(`/` and `../` are the same).

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm no expert on commands, but that seems to be a nasty one (why would you leave an open machine in root user anyway?).

If the files are still on the system (not likely) you should be able to just move them back. But since you are asking this I don't think they are.

My best bet, would be to reinstall the system.

And tell yourself never to leave an oen ROOT system again. :P

Comment: The `/` is the root folder, it has no parent. Why do you feel there has been a change serious enough to ask for a reinstall?

Comment: That's what I tought, thanks for the quick reply. Guess I will always log out even if I leave the desk a few minutes to get some coffee :-(

Comment: @Jobin Note that the command is `mv /* ../`, not `mv /* /..`. The latter is a no-op. The former moves every non-hidden file from the root directory to the parent directory *relative to the current working directory*. If you have just opened a shell, then this is typically `/home` (for non-root users having a home dir like `/home/user/`) or `/` (for the root user at `/root/`).

Comment: @Lekensteyn Ah, so the files may actually just be moved to /home/ folder. Then it should be no problem moving them all back.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Are you sure `mv /* ../` moves files `relative to the current directory` and not to `the absolute path`.

Comment: @Jobin yes, of course. That's how all commands work, `../` is relative to your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it is actually relatively easy to undo a wrong move. The command `mv /* ../` moves every non-hidden file at your top-level directory to the parent of your *current working directory*.

If you were logged in as root, then your current working directory is `/root` by default. In that case, the command `mv /* ../` does not have any effect as it is effectively translated to `mv /* /`.

Since you mentioned that "your system is bricked", I assume that you were unlucky and your current directory is not `/root` (or anything with the parent directory `/`). Let's say that you were in the directory `/var/www`. Now, this means that all files were moved to the directory `/var/`.

Since none of the programs will start (libraries are not accessible, programs are broken too), I suggest to boot into a Live CD and proceed with recovery. In the following commands, replace `$ROOT` by the mountpoint of your Ubuntu installation (e.g. `/media/Ubuntu`).

Let's see what is contained in the root directory:

```
$ ls $ROOT
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
initrd.img    # symlink to /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-34-generic
lib
lib32
lib64
lost+found    # special directory for ext filesystems, cannot be moved
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
selinux
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
vmlinuz    # symlink to boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-34-generic
```

The glob pattern `/*` is expanded by the shell, so the command becomes something like:

```
mv /bin /boot (stripped for saving space) /usr /var /vmlinuz  /var/
```

If `/var/` did not contain any of the names from `/`, then you could simply move it back. Assuming that your current working directory is `/var` (`cd /var`), you can run:

```
mv bin boot (stripped for saving space) usr var vmlinuz $ROOT/
```

Or do it one-by-one:

```
mv bin $ROOT/
mv boot $ROOT/
...
mv var $ROOT/
mv vmlinuz $ROOT/
```

Special cases:

- When a directory in `/var/` has the same name as a directory in `/`, then the directory is *not* moved. This is the case for `/run/` and `/var/run/`.

Special cases that are not applicable here, but mentioned for completeness:

- When a directory in `/var/` has the same name as an item in `/` (directory, files, symlinks, etc.), then the item from `/` will be moved into the directory of `/var/NAME`. For example, if `/NAME` is a file or directory and `/var/NAME/` is a directory, then `/NAME` will be moved to `/var/NAME/NAME`.
- When `/var/NAME` is a file and `/NAME` is a file too, then `/var/NAME` is overwritten with `/NAME`. Recovery is not so easy here as you need forensics tools now.
- When `/var/NAME` is a file and `/NAME` is a directory, then nothing will happen (and an error message is printed).

---

Next time do not forget to lock your screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) and hint the "not so nice guy" that data loss is not a nice New Year present ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on which directory your root shell was left open in. The command `mv /* ../` will move everything from the `/` folder to the parent folder of your *current* directory.

Now, the main issue you will have is that no commands will work since `/bin` will now be  `/home/bin` (assuming your root shell's working directory was your `$HOME`). This can easily be solved by booting into a live session, mounting your local drive and moving the files back.

You can also try running `/home/bin/ls /home`. If that shows you folders like `/usr` and `/etc`, you know that your `/` files have been moved to /home` and you can get them back by running (from the open root shell):

```
/home/bin/mv /home/{bin,boot,dev,etc,lib,lib32,lib64,media,mnt,opt,proc,root,run,sbin,srv,sys,tmp,usr,var} /
```